# Processing feedback about duplicate rows on bulk insert

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a service that allows users to import multiple items at once besides filling the form, uploading the csv file where each row is representing an item - entity using an id that is set under an unique field in my mysql database (only one item with specific id can exist).

When user finishes with the upload and csv processing, I would like to provide feedback about what items in their file already existed in the database. I decided to go with INSERT IGNORE, parsing the id's out of warnings (regex) and retrieving item information (SELECT) based on collected id's. Browsing the internet, I did not find the common solution for this so I would like to know if this approach is correct, specially when dealing with larger number of rows (500+).

Base idea:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO (id, name, address, phone) VALUES (x,xx,xxx,xxxx), (y,yy,yyy,yyyy), etc;

SHOW WARNINGS;

$warning_example = [0=>['Message'=>'Duplicate entry on '123456'...'], 1=>['Message'=>'Duplicate entry on '234567'...']];
$duplicates_count = 0;
foreach($warning_example as $duplicated_item) {
    preg_match('/regex_to_extract_id/', $duplicated_item['Message'], $result);
    $id[$duplicates_count] = $result;
    $duplicates_count++;
}
$duplicates_string = implode(',',$id);

SELECT name FROM items WHERE id IN ($duplicates_string);
```

Also, what would be the simplest and most efficient regex for this task since the message structure is the same every time.

```
Duplicate entry '12345678' for key 'id'
Duplicate entry '23456789' for key 'id'
etc.
```

Comment: Your `$warning_example` array seems to have `Message` as an array, not a string, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is a typo mistake. This is just a quick presentation of what i want to achieve and discuss on my choice. It is not an actual code. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_match`:

```
preg_match(
    "/Duplicate entry '(\d+)' for key 'id'/", 
    $duplicated_item['Message'], 
    $result
);
$id[$duplicates_count] = $result[1];
```

`(\d+)` represents a sequence of digits (`\d`), that should be captured (surrounding parentheses).

---

However, there are better ways to proceed, if you have control over the way the data is imported. To start with, I would recommend first running a `SELECT` statement to check if a record already exists, and running the `INSERT` only when needed. This avoids generating errors on the database side. Also, it is much more accurate than using `INSERT IGNORE`, which basically ignores **all** error that occur during insertion (wrong data type or length, non-nullable value, ...) : for this reason, it is usually not a good tool to check for unicity.

Comment: If the data is being imported directly from a CSV file into MySQL doing a `SELECT` first isn't an option

Comment: @Nick: aggreed, for these remarks to be valid OP needs to have control over the import process. I updated my answer to mention that.